# Cannot use custom-formatter

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak, redhat

Running on java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-2.el8_3.x86_64, WildFly Core 10.1.12.SP1-redhat .
I'm trying to use a custom formatter like this:

```
module add --name=com.my.keycloak.log-formatter-json --resources=/extensions/log-formatter-json.jar --dependencies=org.jboss.logmanager

/subsystem=logging/custom-formatter=custom:add(class=com.my.keycloak.logging.formatter.json.JsonFormatter, module=com.my.keycloak.log-formatter-json, properties={prettyPrint=true,printDetails=true,bufferSize=1024})
```

but always get the following errors:

```
16:41:29,921 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "logging"),
    ("custom-formatter" => "CUSTOM")
]): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load module "com.my.keycloak.log-formatter-json" for formatter "CUSTOM"
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/modules/ModuleLoader
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ModuleFinder.getClassLoader(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:556) [jboss-logmanager-2.1.17.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.1.17.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration.<init>(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:63) [jboss-logmanager-2.1.17.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.1.17.Final-redhat-00001]
    ... 18 more
```

if I tried to add

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/a:$JBOSS_HOME/jboss-modules.jar"
```

then I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
    at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:89)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:352)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:320)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:593)
```

then, I added

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
```

and the issue still persists. Please, help.

P.S. If you think that JAVA_OPTS were not updated, then please see the entire JAVA_OPTS logged during the running.

```
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/eap

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xlog:gc*:file="/opt/eap/standalone/log/gc.log":time,uptimemillis:filecount=5,filesize=3M -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/eap/jboss-modules.jar -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom  -javaagent:/opt/jboss/container/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/opt/jboss/container/jolokia/etc/jolokia.properties -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.3.3.CP/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.1.17.Final-redhat-00001.jar:/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/org/glassfish/jakarta/json/main/jakarta.json-1.1.6.redhat-00001.jar:/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/javax/json/api/main/jakarta.json-api-1.1.6.redhat-00001.jar:/opt/eap/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.3.3.CP/org/wildfly/common/main/wildfly-common-1.5.2.Final-redhat-00002.jar -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Dsun.util.logging.disableCallerCheck=true  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're error is caused by the issue described in [WFCORE-4748](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFCORE-4748). This should is fixed in WildFly 21 and should be fixed in JBoss EAP 7.4.

Another thing to note is there is no need to use the KeyCloak formatter like that. There is one built into JBoss EAP 7.3 which it seems you're using.

```
/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=custom:add(pretty-print=true, print-details=true})
```

Comment: In my custom formatter I use some additional values to be displayed
```
environmentName = System.getenv(ENV_NAME_ENVIRONMENT);
``` 
So, I believe, a built-in one formatter is not enough.

Comment: but how to pass environment variables to that json-formatter?

Comment: I did this using 
ENTRYPOINT ./standalone.sh -c standalone-openshift.xml -DvarEnv=$MY_ENVIRONMENT . Is there any better approach? 
@James R. Perkins

Comment: Ye the `meta-data` would be what you want. You can use expressions for the values so something like `${env.MY_ENVIRONMENT}` can be used.

Comment: No, unfortunately ${env.MY_ENVIRONMENT} is not working when used in the attributes. They appear as a normal string then.

Comment: but here is the workaround:
./standalone.sh -c standalone-openshift.xml -DvarEnv=$MY_ENVIRONMENT
and only using ${varEnv} in the attributes is a solution.

Comment: Ah my apologies. I forgot about OpenShift as it's slightly different. What you're doing should work fine though.